# Mismatched property value in styled components

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, eslint, styled-components

When I use props inside my styled component I just keep getting error mismatched property error. I use WebStorm Inspector code tool and ESLint.

This is my .eslint.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true,
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "redux-saga"
    ]
}
```

And this is my styled component

```
export const LabelButton = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
  background: ${(props) => (props.active ? "#1E88E5" : "#2196f3")};
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
`;
```

When I run inspect code I get this:
[image: WebStorm error]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotation marks from the color properties: like this

```
  background: orange
```

instead of

```
background: 'orange'
```